# Is List<T> thread-safe for reading?

Tags: c#, list, parallel-processing

Is the following pseudocode thread-safe ?

```
IList<T> dataList = SomeNhibernateRepository.GetData();

Parallel.For(..i..)
{
    foreach(var item in dataList)
    {
       DoSomething(item);
    }
}
```

The list never gets changed, it's only iterated and read in parallel. No writing to fields or something like that whatsoever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, `List<T>` is fine to read from multiple threads concurrently, so long as nothing's writing.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1#thread-safety):

> A `List<T>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.

EDIT: Note that your code doesn't *necessarily* use `List<T>` - just an `IList<T>`. Do you know the type returned by `GetData()`? If you're in control of `GetData()` you probably want to document that the list returned by it is thread-safe for reading, if it's actually returning a `List<T>`.

Comment: What about calling find() on an instance variable List from within a singleton method? Could the results possibly get returned to the wrong user?

Comment: @eaglei22: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean - I suggest you ask a new question with much more context. But fundamentally I doubt that it would just be `Find` that's a problem - if you've got multiple threads modifying a single `List<T>` without protection, that's fundamentally a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Sorry for the confusion. If two users access a method within a singleton class:
GetCode(string code) => return conditionCodes.Find(x => x.Code.Equals(code));  the List object "conditionCodes" only get populated never changed. Is concurrent access safe? I will will add a new question if this is still confusing. Thank you.

Comment: @eaglei22: Yes, that's a case of multiple readers with no modification, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's fully thread-safe as long as `DoSomething(item)` doesn't modify `dataList`. Since you said it doesn't, then yes, that is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure no one is going to change your list, you could access it through an `IEnumerable`

```
IEnumerable<T> dataList = SomeNhibernateRepository.GetData();

Parallel.For(..i..)
{
    foreach(var item in dataList)
    {
       DoSomething(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: That could still be cast back to a List<T>. You could return List<T>.AsReadOnly(), but even so the original list is accessible with reflection.

Comment: if you cast back the List<T> you still can't modify the original list
If you are considering the reflection you could  circumvent runtime checks as well . 
how can you make a field private? you may anwer with the private keywork. I may answer you with the reflection I can access it.

Answer (score -1):

If whay you say is correct then I would say so. But what you say or think may not what happen in reality. How can you say in code what you have said. How to enforce the constraint that List is never modified?

Comment: That's relatively easy: make it a private member in a class which only performs read access to the list, possibly exposing the values via other members. The class needs to be kept under control, but it's a single piece of code to look at.