# Use ConcurrentBag<T> or equivalent with LINQ in a Thread Safe way

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a class that returns a `List<T>` of transactions.
I need to query that list with `Linq` (or equivalent) inside a `Parallel.ForEach` loop, since I need a subset of those transactions for each cycle. The subset contains transactions of a specific customer.

So my case is that the `List<T>` contains all transactions and I want to parallelize the elaboration per customer.
The subset `List<T>` of customer's transactions then it is passed as parameter to another class method to do the elaboration.

Each cicle will only need to **READ** from the main `List<T>` of transactions and will take always different subset of transactions, since they're grouped by customer id.

The `ServiceItems` and `TransactionProcessor` classes are on .NET 3.5... otherwise I could use `ConcurrentBag<T>` directly on them.
The `ProcessTransactions` method instead, is inside a .NET 4.5 project.

I want to know if my approach can be considered thread safe, maybe just because the transactions are accessed in read-only mode. Or otherwise if it is not, how I can make it works right.

Sample code:

```
public void ProcessTransactions
{
    ServiceItems items = new ServiceItems();

    // Call the method that retrieves the transactions for all customers
    items.Initialize(); 

    ConcurrentBag<ItemsGroup<TransactionItem>> itemsBag
        = new ConcurrentBag<ItemsGroup<TransactionItem>>(items.ItemsGroups);

    ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> customers = GetCustomers(
        items.CustomersIds.Select(id => id.ToString()).ToList());

    Parallel.ForEach(customers, options, (customer, state) =>
    {
        int customerId = customer.Key;

        // Is this Thread Safe?
        List<ItemsGroup<TransactionItem>> customerItems = itemsBag
            .Where(g => g.CustomerId == customerId).ToList();

        // This is the transactions processor class
        TransactionsProcessor processor = new TransactionsProcessor();

        // This method accepts a List<ItemsGroup<TransactionItem>> object
        // for customer transactions
        processor.StartForCustomer(customerId, customerItems);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Evk.

This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955819/is-listt-thread-safe-for-reading) that clarify the usage of `List<T>` in a multi thread environment.
And see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569747/are-linq-operations-on-concurrent-collections-thread-safe) about Linq on `List<T>`.

Comment: You don't need any concurrent collections here, since you are only reading from them.

Comment: So you're saying that if I only need to read I can always use a normal List? Maybe I'm wrong but I seem to remember to have read that this is not so... Anyway, what if I also need to write?

Comment: Yes, reading collection from multiple threads is fine as long as you never write. If you write (that is adding or removing items) then its not safe and you need locks or concurrent collections. This applies generally - all immutable (read only) objects are thread safe.

Comment: Just to enforce the immutability you could use the classes from the [`System.Collections.Immutable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.immutable.aspx) namespace or at least return your lists as [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) interface.

Comment: Another case... What if the customer's subset of transactions (`customerItems`) used by the processor method (`StartForCustomer(customerId, customerItems)`) is changed inside the `StartForCustomer` method? Like a cicle: `foreach (Transaction in transactions) { transaction.Processed = true; transaction.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now; }`. Is there any problem using `List`?